# How many ways are there to declare a float in Rust?

Tags: variables, rust, floating-point

I have seen the following possibilities:

```rust
let first_float: f64 = 3.4;
let second_float = 4.5f64;
let third_float = 5.6 as f64;
```

Are there any other ways to declare a float? I don't mean the different floating-point types like `f32` and `f64`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure there are.

First let's explain what your ways do. They combine different features of the language, and while they all seem to "declare a float in Rust", they are not simple declarations.

```
// Float literals will become either `f32` or `f64`
// depending on how they're are used:
let first_float: f64 = 3.4;

// This one is really a `f64` literal,
// typically only used when inference isn't enough
let second_float = 4.5f64; 

// This is an identity cast, the untyped literal will give f64 since that
// is what is needed at the end. I would never use this.
let third_float = 5.6 as f64;
```

Floats are `f64` default, so this is what you should use most of the time:

```rust
let _another_one = 3.4;
```

And here are a few other over-complicated ways:

```rust
let _another_one = 17./5.; // good old math
let _another_one: f64 = From::from(3.4); // From::from identity conversion
let _another_one = f64::from(3.4); // Same as above, no inference
let _another_one = "3.4".parse::<f64>().unwrap(); // Why not parse them?
let _another_one = f64::from_bits(4614838538166547251); // When you really need your bits right
let _another_one = unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<_, f64>(4614838538166547251u64) }; // same as above, but only if you want to be naughty
let (_another_one,): (f64,) = (3.4,); // Deconstructing a one-tuple.

// Deserialize from JSON:
let _another_one: f64 = {
    use serde; // 1.0.104
    use serde_json; // 1.0.44
    serde_json::from_str("3.4").unwrap()
};

// This requires #![feature(type_ascription)] at the moment:
let _another_one = 3.4 : f64;
```

Comment: What about [`from_bits`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.from_bits)? ;)

Comment: since `f64` and `f32` both are `Deserialize`, you can also `f64::deserialize(d).unwrap()` for any `d` which is `serde::Deserializer`.